# Are all language over $\Sigma= \{0\}$ decidable?

Tags: formal-languages

I have problem in determine whether it is decidable or not, can somebody help me please

Comment: The language $\{0^{BB(n)}: n\ge2\}$ is undecidable, where $BB(n)$ is the infamous busy-beaver function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A language over $\{0\}$ is any subset of the set S of all strings consisting of a finite number of 0s. S is countable, the set of all subsets of S is uncountable.

Any decidable language must be decided by some algorithm. The set of algorithms, no matter how you describe it, is countable, not uncountable. Therefore some subsets of S (actually almost all) are not decidable.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider any undecidable language $L$ (for example, take the language  $Halt = \{(M,x): \text{ M halts on x}\}$), we can encode each string of this language in unary (by writing the binary number representing $(M,x)$ in unary using $0$ as the symbol) to get a language $L_0 \subseteq \{0\}^*$. It’s not hard to see that $L_0$ will also be undecidable because $L$ is.